# Self excited dynamo

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

Hello everyone! In the picture above ( taken from the Asian Physics Olympiad of 2009, problem 2) a metallic disc of radius a mounted on a slender axle is rotating with a constant angular velocity
ω inside a long solenoid of inductance L whose two ends are connected to the rotating disc by two
brush contacts as shown. The total resistance of the whole circuit is R . A small magnetic
disturbance can initiate the growth of an induced electromotive force across the terminals P, Q.

In order for the system to be a self excited dynamo , shouldn't the coil be spiralled in the opposite direction , in order to create an opposite magnetic field?

Thanks !

Comment: I mean , in the case above, if you have an initial current, the current as a function of time will decrease. But the problem has at the solution a possible increasing in the current due to the angular speed. Isn't this(last one) the case for an opposite magnetic field?